# Cordova build failure with cordova version 10.0.0 and node v16.4.2

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

everyone.
I have a problem with Cordova when I gonna make an apk file or using "cordova run android" command.
I make a new project and after that, I added the android platform to my project and finally, I use this command: "cordova build android" and got this error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\amir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\amir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\amir\Desktop\Application\amir\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\amir\Desktop\Application\amir\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

This is my system information and everything of my Cordova such as the variable environment:

```
cordova -version 10.0.0
node -v v16.4.2
java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
Gradle -version  Gradle 6.5!
```

---

cordova requirements android --verbose

```
Platform API successfully found in: C:\Users\amir\Desktop\Application\amir\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
No android targets (SDKs) installed!
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-7.0.2\bin\gradle
Some of requirements check failed
CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at C:\Users\amir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:422:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

---

[image]
[image]

What is the problem? I used from these version of gradles:
gradle-4.9
gradle-5.0
gradle-6.5
gradle-7.0.2
But I still have got this error.
When I use this command "sdkmanager --list" I will get this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "No android targets (SDKs) installed!" - Maybe install android SDK ?

Comment: I solved that error but still have an error. I still have the gradle error.: cordova requirements android --verbose
Platform API successfully found in: C:\Users\amir\Desktop\Application\amir\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-30,android-29,android-28
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-7.0.2\bin\gradle